# What are the differences between @class method, @static method, and a normal function and how do I use them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get into Object-Oriented Programming for Python, but I definitely don't have the Programming literacy to understand any guides out there. I would be grateful if anyone could help me understand how to use and clarify the differences between "normal functions", "@class method", and "@static method" in a way that a beginner like me could understand.

A guide that I had no clue how to use, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Object State**

Object state is the state of your variables inside the scope of an object.

**Class State**

Class state is the state of your variables which are defined class-wide. Class variables are available to all instances of that class, not instance specific that is.

**Instance Methods**

You call these normal functions, these are used to interact with object state. They get/set or do stuff with your variables inside the object.

**Class Methods**

These have access to the class-wide variables and may perform operations on them, but they cannot modify object state, obviously.

**Static Methods**

These are not related to the class or the objects derived from that class in anyway. It is a normal function that can be very well defined outside of the scope of your class. You define methods as static just to apply namespacing on them.